# Bitcoinj: How to get notified when coins are received

Tags: wallet, bitcoinj, receiving

I need to know when my local wallet receives coins... but `onCoinsReceived` is invoked as soon as a transaction on my wallet is visible. How do I get notified when coins have been received and are spendable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically speaking, the coins are spendable immediately; they'll just take longer to spend and cost more in transaction fees. But to know when the coins are confirmed, in onCoinsRecieved:

> If you want to know when such a transaction receives its first confirmation, register a TransactionConfidence event listener using the object retrieved via Transaction.getConfidence(). It's safe to modify the wallet in this callback, for example, by spending the transaction just received.

([Source.](https://bitcoinj.github.io/javadoc/0.12/org/bitcoinj/core/AbstractWalletEventListener.html#onCoinsReceived-org.bitcoinj.core.Wallet-org.bitcoinj.core.Transaction-org.bitcoinj.core.Coin-org.bitcoinj.core.Coin-))

Use something like this:

```
public void onCoinsReceived(Wallet wallet,
                            Transaction tx,
                            Coin prevBalance,
                            Coin newBalance) {
    TransactionConfidence confidence = Transaction.getConfidence();
    confidence.addEventListener(new TransactionConfidence.Listener() {
        public void onConfidenceChanged(Transaction tx,
                         TransactionConfidence.Listener.ChangeReason reason) {
            DefaultCoinSelector.isSelectable(transaction) {
                // do something here
            }
        }
    });
}
```