# NBitcoin how can I get notify when I receive coins?

Tags: receiving, nbitcoin

I something like `onCoinReceived` in bitcoinj

[Example with bitcoinj](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/40743/bitcoinj-how-to-get-notified-when-coins-are-received)

Answer (score 1):

NBitcoin is only a library. In order to get notified upon receipt of funds you would need to be running a bitcoin implementation such as bitcoin-core and use it's JSON-RPC, or ZMQ or it's built-in features like `walletnotify`.

https://github.com/NicolasDorier/NBitcoin.Docs/blob/master/README.md

[How do I use walletnotify?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/24457/how-do-i-use-walletnotify)

Answer (score 0):

Use NBXplorer for notifications: https://github.com/dgarage/NBXplorer/blob/master/docs/API.md#websocket